# Jquery Mobile - Option is not added dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile latest version. I have a select field that actually look like this:

```
<select id="make">
</select>
```

I want to dynamically added option on it.So I use this code :

```
var makeArr = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
var parent = $('#make');
$.each(makeArr, function(i, item){
   parent.append('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
});
```

I have also use `parent.append('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>').trigger('create');` but nothing change.

I have added `<li>` under `<ul>` by this way.But this is not working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$("#make").selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

after inserting dynamic content.

Comment: Thanks dude! Actually I also used `$('#idname').listview('refresh');` while generating the listview.In jquery mobile, can every dom be refreshed in such way?

Comment: No not all elements can be refreshed. For example `input type=radio` can only be 'refreshed' when you call the trigger('create') on the **page**: `$("#page-id").trigger("create")` will recreate the page with the new dynamic content.